# Understanding Channel in Convolution Neural Network (CNN) input shape and output shape

Tags: keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I was trying to follow this tutorial
https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

In the baseline model it has 
`model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(3, 150, 150)))`

I don't quite follow the output shape here. If input shape is 3x150x150 with a kernel size 3x3, isn't the output shape 3x148x148? (Assuming no padding). However, according to Keras Doc:

> Output shape: 4D tensor with shape: (batch, filters, new_rows,
>   new_cols)

That seems to me output shape will be 32x148x148. My question is whether this understanding correct? If so, where do the additional filters come from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the input shape is `(3, 150, 150)`, after applying Conv2D layer the output is `(?, 32, 148, 148)`. Check it out with following example:

```
inps = Input(shape=(3, 150, 150))
conv = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), data_format='channels_first')(inps)
print(conv)
>> Tensor("conv2d/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 32, 148, 148), dtype=float32)
```

- The first dimension which specified by `?` symbol is batch size.
- The second dimension is filter size (`32`).
- The two last are image width and height (`148`).

---

*How do channels change from 3 to 32?* Let's assume we have RGB image (3 channels) and the output channel size is 1. The following things happen:

[image]

When you use `filters=32` and `kernel_size=(3,3)`, you are creating 32 different filters, each of them with shape (3,3,3). The result will bring 32 different convolutions. Note that, according to [Keras](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/), all kernels initialize by `glorot_uniform` at the beginning.

Image from this [blog post](http://machinelearninguru.com/computer_vision/basics/convolution/convolution_layer.html).

Comment: Thank you. Part of my question is how does 3 channel images get an output of 32 channels (or filters). I get the point of updated width and height and batch size.

Comment: @clwen you set filters to 32 which means for each image it generated 32 feature map or channel.

Comment: Thanks for the edit with figure. In this case we are getting 32 copies of 148x148 that are identical? Since we didn't specify different bias/kernel for each of the 32 filters.

Comment: When you use filters=32 and kernel_size=(3,3), you are creating 32 different filters, each of them with length (3,3). The result will bring 32 different convolutions. By default, bias is zero.

Comment: I see. there is a kernel_initializer. If we do not pass anything, the kernel still gets initialized with randomness with the default one. (according to the doc the default is glorot_uniform)